# Creating a ranked list from multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have 3 arrays that return a url,title,snippet and score from 3 different search engines, the score starts at 100 for the element in the array, the second 99 and so on, I'm trying to combine all 3 into one array. If the urls match from the different arrays I want to add the scores together and then delete the duplicate url. If there is no match between the urls then I just want to put this element into the combined array.
 The final combined list should contain all distinct urls with its score,title and snippet, here are my array structures

googleArray

```
$x=0;
$score=100;
foreach ($js->items as $item)
    {   
        $googleArray[$x]['link'] = ($item->{'link'});
        $googleArray[$x]['title'] = ($item->{'title'});
        $googleArray[$x]['snippet'] = ($item->{'snippet'});
        $googleArray[$x]['score'] = $score--;
        $x++;
    }
```

blekkoArray

```
$score = 100; 
foreach ($js->RESULT as $item)
{           
$blekkoArray[$i]['url'] = ($item->{'url'});         
$blekkoArray[$i]['title'] = ($item->{'url_title'});
$blekkoArray[$i]['snippet'] = ($item->{'snippet'});
$blekkoArray[$i]['score'] = $score--;      // assign the $score value here
$i++;

}
```

bingArray

```
foreach($jsonObj->d->results as $value)
    {   $i = 0;

        $bingArray[]['Url'] = ($value->{'Url'});            
        $bingArray[]['Title'] = ($value->{'Title'});
        $bingArray[]['Description'] = ($value->{'Description'});
        $bingArray[]['score'] = $score--;
        $i++;
    }
```

Any help would be great, thanks in advance

Comment: $i is useless in bingArray. Also why do you have different names in different arrays: link, url, Url? It will complicate problem solving.

Comment: link, url  and Url are the names that the differant search engines put into the array, but yes I can change the assignment in the arrays but thats the least of my problems

Comment: Yes, it would be better if all the arrays had the same key names for similar data to unify the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution depends on a couple of things to work. First, the `url` and `score` keys need to be the same, i.e. all lower case and none that are "link." Secondly, the URLs have to be normalized, because they serve as the key for the array. If there are any differences in the URLs, they will show up more than once in the final array.

```
$merged = array_merge($googleArray, $blekkoArray);
$merged = array_merge($merged, $bingArray);
$combined = array();
foreach ($merged as $key => $value){
    $score = (isset($combined[$value['url']]['score'])) ? $value['score'] + $combined[$value['url']]['score'] : $value['score'];
    $combined[$value['url']] = $value;
    $combined[$value['url']]['score'] = $score;
}
```

If you don't want to keep the URLs as the key, add this line:

```
$combined = array_values($combined);
```

If you want to sort the array by score, you can use `usort`:

```
usort($combined, function ($a, $b){
    return $b['score'] - $a['score'];
});
print_r($combined);
```